# Can’t install f.lux

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, package

I try to install *f.lux*, but after write

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get:

```
W: Can’t fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

So I cannot install f.lux, I tried to see at /etc/apt/sources.list and check the f.lux files, but the update failed.

I saw that it can be a problem of version.

What can I do?

Comment: this is more for `superuser` but anyway, 404 is very clear.. It's not there.. You will need to verify the repo! Also what ubuntu version are you running ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 15.04. I tried to see if there were other repo, but all commands were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow the guidelines from this gist - https://gist.github.com/robertboloc/9feaa9150926efa4175a

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2 python-appindicator
git clone https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet.git
cd f.lux-indicator-applet
chmod +x setup.py
sudo ./setup.py install
fluxgui
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) Is this the real version of f.lux or is it a customised fork?

Comment: https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet - based on the age of the files, it looks like the real version, but I'm not sure..

Comment: Thanks, I like the version you give me. It’s gone be all right. 

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 you will need to add python-pexpect and python-gonf packages as well to your apt-get install command

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the repo has been dead. Reading through [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y09KeWBVzV4J:https://justgetflux.com/forum/topic/108/seems-like-the-repo-is-dead-i-get-a-404-not-found-error/5%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), it is mentioned that the Windows version installed via WINE seems to work sufficiently.

That's a shame, as I use F.lux on every machine.

Comment: Oh, no… I don’t really want to use wine. Thanks for your answer. Do you know a similar application?

Comment: get a 120hz monitor! ^^

Comment: @Carapatte I'd take a look at http://jonls.dk/redshift/ Any reason why you're against wine? I believe it'd work almost flawlessly. Goodluck with either path!

Comment: I am not against wine, but I already run a virtual machine on my computer, and I don’t thing wine can also run. But with the Jot eN solution it works. :-)

Comment: Perfect, glad it works @Carapatte

Answer (score 2):

Just upgraded to the new LTS and Thank God somebody made a version that works under 16.04 !

https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ubuntu/flux

Answer (score 1):

**Correct solution at the bottom**. Jot eN suggested this method

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2 python-appindicator
git clone https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet.git
cd f.lux-indicator-applet
chmod +x setup.py
sudo ./setup.py install
fluxgui
```

which worked fine for installing, but as you launch the application you get greeted by a message to specify long/lat or choose a zip code. After closing this message the program crashes with the error message:

**Error: Please install xflux in the PATH**

This is because xflux doesn't have permission to execute. Some have suggested that typing

```
which xflux
```

gives you the path to xflux. For me it didn't. Instead I tried to run xflux simply by typing it which gave me:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/xflux: Permission denied
```

And using the following statement it was afterwards possible to run fluxgui without having the popup window crash it:

```
sudo chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/xflux
```

Here is a complete version:

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2 python-appindicator
git clone https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet.git
cd f.lux-indicator-applet
chmod +x setup.py
sudo ./setup.py install
sudo chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/xflux
fluxgui
```

Answer (score 0):

> using command line 
>   `1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
>    2. sudo apt-get update
>    3. sudo apt-get install fluxgui`

then type flux in search area .
once if you found the you are successfully done